# How can Max Tennyson and Verdona have kids?

Tags: ben-10

How can Max and Verdona have kids if Anodites don't have DNA?

Comment: The wikia suggests that it's some form of cloning; http://ben10.wikia.com/wiki/Anodite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Parthenogenesis is the most likely process by which the Anodites reproduce with alien partners.

> **[Parthenogenesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenogenesis)** is a form of asexual reproduction in which growth and development of embryos occur without fertilization. In animals, parthenogenesis means development of an embryo from an unfertilized egg cell and is a component process of apomixis.
>
> **Parthenogenesis:** Development of an embryo directly from an egg cell without fertilization is called parthenogenesis. It is of two types:
>
> **Haploid parthenogenesis:** Parthenogenesis of a normal haploid egg (a meiotically reduced egg) into an embryo is termed haploid parthenogenesis. If the mother plant was diploid, then the haploid embryo that results is monoploid, and the plant that grows from the embryo is sterile. If they are not sterile, they are sometimes useful to plant breeders (especially in potato breeding, see dihaploidy). This type of apomixis has been recorded in Solanum nigrum, Lilium spp., Orchis maculata, Nicotiana tabacum, etc.
>
> **Diploid parthenogenesis:** When the megagametophyte develops without completing meiosis, so that the megagametophyte and all cells within it are meiotically unreduced (aka diploid, but diploid is an ambiguous term), this is called diploid parthenogenesis, and the plant that develops from the embryo will have the same number of chromosomes as the mother plant. Diploid parthenogenesis is a component process of gametophytic apomixis (see above).

While the concepts listed here are primarily plant-oriented, with sufficient technological sophistication, there is no reason it could not be applied to more advanced forms of life.

Since Dwayne McDuffie's canon says:

> **[Anodites](http://ben10.wikia.com/wiki/Anodite)** lack DNA. Therefore, any child an Anodite produces with another species, will be related to that Anodite via parentage, but biologically the offspring will remain 100% pure to the species of the other parent.

This implies:

- They either replicate the DNA of their partner using a chemical process by which they initiate cellular replication, essentially creating a clone of their partner.
- It is also possible they are utilizing another source of DNA for the replication if their goal is to NOT create a clone of their partner. Manipulation of DNA information seems well within the range of an experienced Anodite. They could also be utilizing advanced alien technology far beyond the capacity of Humanity.
- It may also imply the process by which the Anodites reproduce does contain some sort of information transfer (like DNA but unique to the Anodite species) which allows information regarding inheritance.

Comment: Very thorough answer! +1

Comment: I don't get it. If Anodites don't have DNA, then how come Gwen is classed as half Human half Anodite? I understand Ben not being half Anodite, but not Gwen